# Why does this script prompt me for an InputObject?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that is supposed to list all the installed programs on a machine.  I want it to export it to a file for me.

I keep getting the error:

> Supply Values for the following parameters: InputObject:

I'm missing something with my script below. I'm still new to powershell, and there's something wrong with the syntax I'm not getting.

How can I resolve this?

---

```
$loc = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

$names = $loc |foreach-object {Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath}

foreach ($name in $names)
{
Write-Host $name.Displayname
}
Export-Csv c:\products.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`Export-Csv` wants an object to write into `c:\products.txt`.

From what you've posted, it's unclear what you want in there. What do you want c:\products.txt to contain?

Comment: I want it to display all the $names

Sorry I'm a pretty bad programmer.  I only am doing this at my job because I'm struggled through it before and written a few other scripts with the help of google.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($name in $names) {
    Write-Host $name
    Add-Content c:\products.txt $name
}
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to address what was asked in the question (turn this into more of a teachable moment)?